# ¿Cómo generar quinquenios en r studio?

Tags: r, rstudio, r-dplyr

Estoy trabajando en una base de datos que contiene las variables `year`(año), `muncode`(clave del municipio) y `ampolaH`( hectáreas erradicadas de amapola). La variable `ampolaH` tiene valores por municipio desde 1990 hasta 2015. Dado lo anterior, la pregunta es cómo hago para generar 5 cortes de la variable `ampolaH` en los que el valor para cada quinquenio sea el promedio de los valores para los años previos. Hasta el momento he podido generar quinquenios por separado con el siguiente código en Rstudio:

```
tesis %>% 
   select(year,muncode,ampolaH ) %>% 
   filter(year>=1996 & year<=2000 ) %>% 
   group_by(muncode) %>%
   summarise(promedio=mean(ampolaH))
```

No obstante, lo que quiero es que r genere los 5 quinquenio en la misma columna y que sean los promedios de los años previos que componen el quinquenio

Answer (score 1):

La parte fundamental de tu pregunta es calcular los quinquenios. Supongamos un `data.frame` similar a lo que comentas:

```
set.seed(2020)
tesis <- data.frame(year = sample(c(1990:2015), 1000, replace = TRUE),
                    muncode = sample(1:5, 1000, replace = TRUE),
                    ampolaH = runif(1000))
```

Para establecer el quinquenio de cada observación podemos usar la función `cut()`:

```
cut(tesis$year, 5) %>% 
  head()

[1] (1990,1995] (2000,2005] (1990,1995] (1990,1995] (1995,2000] (2005,2010]
Levels: (1990,1995] (1995,2000] (2000,2005] (2005,2010] (2010,2015]
```

Ahora, si quieres el promedio de cada quinquenio en una fila por municipio, puedes hacer algo así:

```
tesis %>% 
  mutate(quinquenio = as.integer(cut(year, 5))) %>% 
  group_by(quinquenio, muncode) %>%
  summarise(promedio=mean(ampolaH)) %>% 
  spread(quinquenio, promedio)

# A tibble: 5 x 6
  muncode   `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`
    <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1       1 0.426 0.480 0.534 0.488 0.479
2       2 0.509 0.566 0.401 0.546 0.484
3       3 0.511 0.458 0.481 0.424 0.514
4       4 0.499 0.554 0.491 0.516 0.529
5       5 0.516 0.470 0.523 0.503 0.527
```